# How to make a div scroll to stick inside a div and under another div?

Tags: html, css

I tried to create a webpage that won't scroll the entire page, but just scroll in the card, in the snippet below, just assume that the teal box is the card. I want the `sticky` to stick under the `h2` and also make `h2` position fixed, not to the topmost of the page.

The `sticky` works normally when `top: 0`.

```css
div.article {
  background: #ccffee;
  padding: 30px;
}
div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

div.two {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.content {
  height: 500px;
  background: #ffc0cb;
}
```

```html
<h1>Web Title</h1>
<div class="article">
<h2>Title</h2>
<div class="sticky one">Sticky Stack 1</div>
<div class="sticky two">Sticky Stack 2</div>

<div class="content">Some example text..</div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work when I assign `top` to more than `0`.

```css
div.article {
  background: #ccffee;
  padding: 30px;
}
div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 30;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

div.two {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.content {
  height: 500px;
  background: #ffc0cb;
}
```

```html
<h1>Web Title</h1>
<div class="article">
<h2>Title</h2>
<div class="sticky one">Sticky Stack 1</div>
<div class="sticky two">Sticky Stack 2</div>

<div class="content">Some example text..</div>
</div>
```

What's actually wrong on this `sticky` and how can I resolve this to get the desired appearance?
Is it also possible for me to make the `two` just fully appear when the scrolling point just get there, I mean, the `div.one` will not have any scroll animation/cropped by the boundaries, when the user scroll down 3 times, it will just get the `two` appears in a blink and the `one` already placed at the top/disappeared and that also for scroll up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `px` to the end of your `top` value:

`top:30px;`;

```css
div.article {
  background: #ccffee;
  padding: 30px;
}

div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

div.two {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.content {
  height: 500px;
  background: #ffc0cb;
}

.heading {
  top:10px;
  position:sticky;
}
```

```html
<h1>Web Title</h1>
<div class="article">
  <div class="heading"><h2>Title</h2></div>
  <div class="sticky one">Sticky Stack 1</div>
  <div class="sticky two">Sticky Stack 2</div>
  <div class="content">Some example text..</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I make the "Title" sticky to the top, then the `sticky stack` will have the topmost it can reach is under the `Title`?

Comment: By `Title` do you mean the `h2` title tag?

Comment: Yes, it is. the `<h2>Title</h2>`

Comment: I've updated the answer. The heading is 10 pixels from the top of the screen and the sticky stack is 50 pixels from the top – and they're both sticky